# Why we don't write var before function parameters in a JS

Tags: javascript

When defining a variable in JS, you should precede it with the keyword `var`.

ex:
`var age = 19;`

*But* when passing a variable as a function parameter, you don't put `var`.

ex:

```
function myFunction(name) {
    alert(name);
}
```

*Why?*

Comment: because it is implied

Comment: are you expecting like `myFunction(var name)`??? crazy.

Comment: While `var` and `let` would be redundant, I wonder if they're considering `const` parameters to enforce immutability.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's redundant. `var` disambiguates the scope of a variable. The scope of a function parameter is already clear and does not need any further disambiguation.

Comment: Yes.  Contrast this with TypeScript where the return type is declared:

Comment: `get className(): string {
        return this._object.className;
    }`

Comment: Not sure how that relates to the use of `var`…!?